# Put semi transparent style in Android

Tags: android, styles

I have the following style that shows a new activity, it seems like android:Theme.Dialog:

```
<!-- style tranparent -->
<style name="Theme.TransparentWithBar" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

That I want to do is when this activity be opened, behind activity appears semitransparent because it suppose the action bar in not enabled. Some idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should change theme of activity from manifest file to following:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent".
```